# Change Image Size option in the settings in bulk

Tags: images, block-editor, editor

I was wondering if I can change Image Size option in the post settings panel. From Large to Full Size. Automatically in all posts? I have about 500 posts... :) Seem can not find any answer to that. Thank you!

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to bulk update like this. Do you want to change every image or just the first in a post? Are you familiar with PHP programming in WordPress?

Comment: Ideally i would like to do all, but first would work too, i just need wider size image for Google Discover

Comment: maybe something with database can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you totally right, there is no way to bulk change like that. But i found solution. Since Google Discover uses Featured Images for display, i can add my big size Featured Image to the post `<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>` and hide it with css from the page rendering, but Google will use it as a display image.